# Switch values in two multi-nested maps in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am writing a method in order to replace values in one of two maps depending on if the keys match together. For example lets say we have two maps:

```
def oldmap = [emails: 1, files:[permissions: 3, config:4]]
def replacementmap = [emails: 2, permissions: 5]

// I want this old map to have updated values for keys that match after the method is called.

replacementPermissions(oldmap, replacementmap)

print oldmap

//prints [emails: 2, files:[permissions: 5, config:4]]
```

I have written this method shown below that works for one layered nested map, but I noticed a recursive solution would be a better option instead because my solution wouldn't work for multi-layered nested maps.

```
def replacePermissions(read, params){
    read.each{x,y ->
            temp = x
            if (y instanceof Map){
                y.each{x2,y2->
                    temp = x2
                    params.each{xx,yy->
                        if (temp == xx) y.put(x2, yy)
                        if (yy instanceof Map){
                            yy.each{aa, bb->
                                if (temp == aa) y.put(x2, bb)

                            }
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }

            else{
                params.each{x1,y1->
                    if (temp == x1) read.put(x, y1)
                }
            }
        }

    return read
}
```

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to think of a recursive solution for traversing and matching keys to swap values.

Right now I have this with 
No signature of method: main.swapsearch() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.Integer) values: [[lol3:[lol5:4, lol6:10], lol4:4], 5]
Possible solutions: swapsearch(java.util.Map, java.util.Map)

```
def swapsearch(Map mapa, Map mapb){
    mapa.each{x,y ->
        temp = x
        mapb.each{x1, y1->
            if (y instanceof Map || y1 instanceof Map){
                swapsearch(y, y1)
            }
            else if (temp == x1){
                mapb.put(x, y1)
            }
        }

    }

    mapb
}


Map oldmap = [lol1: 1, lol2:[lol3: [lol5: 4, lol6: 10], lol4:4]]
Map newmap = [lol1: 5, lol5: 111]

print newmap
newmap = swapsearch(oldmap, newmap)
print newmap
```

SOLUTION with help of @injecteer:
I was able to do a simple recursion as so:

```
// Make sure repl map is flattened
def switchMaps( Map src, Map repl ){
  src.each{key,value ->
    if( repl.containsKey(key) ){
      src.put(key, repl[key])

    }
    else if( value && value instanceof Map ){
      replacemaps (value, repl)
    }
  }
  src
}
```

Comment: is your `replacementmap` flat?

Comment: @injecteer not necessarily, could be nested as well. The point is to match keys between two maps (could be nested 99 times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple recursion:

```
Map oldmap = [emails: 1, files:[permissions: 3, config:4, deep:[ deeper:[ verydeep:1 ] ] ] ] 

Map replacementmap = [emails: 2, permissions: 5, verydeep:400]

def replace( Map src, Map repl ){
  src.each{
    if( repl.containsKey( it.key ) )
      it.value = repl[ it.key ]
    else if( it.value && Map.isAssignableFrom( it.value.getClass() ) )
      replace it.value, repl
  }
}

replace oldmap, replacementmap

assert oldmap.emails == replacementmap.emails
assert oldmap.files.permissions == replacementmap.permissions
assert oldmap.files.deep.deeper.verydeep == replacementmap.verydeep
```

If your `replacementmap` is also nested, you have to pre-process it before using, like so:

```
Map replacementmap = [emails: 2, permissions: 5, deep:[ config:300, toodeep:[ verydeep:400 ] ] ]

Map flatten( Map m, Map res = [:] ) {
  m.each{ k, v ->
    if( !v ) return
    if( Map.isAssignableFrom( v.getClass() ) ) flatten v, res
    else res[ k ] = v
  }
  res
}

Map flatRepl = flatten replacementmap 
assert flatRepl == [emails:2, permissions:5, config:300, verydeep:400]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, recursions have always been one of my weakest points. What do you mean by pre-processing? Does that mean you want to pre-process the nested map to a flat map?